# Why am I getting undefined with React props

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass a function from parent to child, but I'm getting "Cannot read property 'getDays' of undefined".

Here are snippets from the parent:

```
getDays:function(){return this.state.days;},

...

  renderComponents:function(){
    if (typeof(this.state.days)==='undefined'){
      var days = 0;
    }else{
      days = this.state.days;
    }
    console.log(days);
    if (this.state.showWorkDoneMaintenance){
      return <WorkDoneMaintenance
        subjects={this.props.subjects}
        workdone={this.props.workdone}
        getDays={this.getDays}
        />;
    }
```

And then here is the child:

```
var WorkDoneMaintenance = React.createClass({
...
  renderWorkDoneItems:function() {
    var items = [];
    this.props.workdone.map(function(workdone){
        if (TimeUtility.dateIsToday(workdone.createdAt,this.props.getDays())){
          items.push(workdone);
      }
    });
    return items.map((workdone) => (
      <tr key={workdone._id}>
...

  propTypes:{
    getDays:React.PropTypes.func,
    subjects:React.PropTypes.array,
    workdone:React.PropTypes.array
  }
});
```

It doesn't seem to have any problem with the arrays that are getting passed (subjects and workdone), but I can't seem to figure out the issue with the function.

Comment: Change `function(workdone){` to `(workdone) => {`

Comment: is there a reason why you are passing the state via a function? why not just pass `getDays={this.state.days}`, also as dominic says above, you need to ether use arrows functions, or bind `this` to your functions for it to work in the relevant context.

Comment: I tried passing it as a state and had the same issue, though I'll be happy to try again.  And why would changing function(workdone) to (workdone) => help?

Comment: Why the workdone)=> syntax. Duh.  the way I had it the this object is no longer the React class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write: `this.props.workdone.map(function(workdone){ ... });` you won't be able to use `this` within the mapping function. That's a common issue in JavaScript, functions created this way simply do not preserve `this`. To fix the problem, use the lambda notation instead, which does preserve `this`: `this.props.workdone.map(workdone => { ... });`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more details